# Insert variable text string (timestamp) into cell with VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, text, copy

I am trying to streamline a process of taking notes on records in a spreadsheet. I want to insert a timestamp (with a specific format) into a cell and then continue typing notes.

This is the code I have in VBA:

```
Sub timestamp()

Dim stringdate As String
Dim stringtime As String
Dim stamp As String




stringdate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")
stringtime = Format(Now(), "hh:mmA/P")
stamp = stringdate & " @" & stringtime & " KB- "


Selection.Value = stamp

'SendKeys "{F2}" /// not working

End Sub
```

This inserts the timestamp in the format I want, but I have two problems. (1) I need to be able to continue typing after I insert the text and the sendkeys is not working. (2) I also want to be able to navigate back to that cell at a later time and insert a new timestamp below with more notes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried a change_event to insert the timestamp to a specific column?  you can make the caveat that if the cell is not blank you move to the next column, etc., so keep a running tally of changes.  If you're actually inserting rows, then that change would be captured.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you want to run a macro while editing a cell. That is impossible. So I'd like to offer a workaround.
Put this in your sheet module:

```
Const MAGIC_CHARACTER = "¤"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim stringdate As String
    Dim stringtime As String
    Dim stamp As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    stringdate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")
    stringtime = Format(Now(), "hh:mmA/P")
    stamp = stringdate & " @" & stringtime & " KB- "

    Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, MAGIC_CHARACTER, stamp)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When you need a timestamp, enter the *magic character*, which must be something you'll never use, but you still have easy access to on your keyboard. In my case, I picked "¤", but you are probably using a different keyboard layout, so pick something that works for you. Once you leave a cell, the magic character is replaced with a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You already got one answer, and here is a somewhat different approach:

You must paste this in the Worksheet module where you will be typing notes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tAddress As Variant
    tAddress = Split(Target.Address, "$")
    If tAddress(1) = "B" And tAddress(2) > 1 Then
        If Cells(tAddress(2), 1).Value = "" Then Cells(tAddress(2), 1) = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy: h:mm:ss AM/PM")
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}", False
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever you select any Cell in column B (With the exception of B1) if the cell next to it on column A is blank it will time stamp it and also activate the cell so you can type on it. Whenever you move to the next cell in column B it will do it again. If you move back to a cell you already typed on, it will NOT change the timestamp, but it can easily be edited to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. I decided on the below code:

```
Sub MyTimestamp()
'
' MyTimestamp Macro
' Insert KB Date/Time stamp into cell
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D



Dim stringdate As String
Dim stringtime As String
Dim stamp As String
Dim current_value As String

stringdate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")
stringtime = Format(Now(), "hh:mmA/P")
stamp = stringdate & " @" & stringtime & " KB- "

current_value = Selection.Value

If current_value = "" Then
Selection.Value = current_value & stamp
Else: Selection.Value = current_value & Chr(10) & stamp
End If


Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "{f2}", True



End Sub
```